# Spring: A bean's init-method is being triggered when invoking other beans

Tags: spring

I'm currently experimenting on bean callback methods and noticed that if I define callback methods for one bean, these methods are also called on other beans.

I have a classes named `x.HelloWorld` (no callbacks) and `y.HelloWorld` (has init and destroy callback methods).

**HelloWorld.java:**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void getMessage() {
        System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
    }
}
```

**HelloWorld2.java:**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void getMessage() {
        System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
    }

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Bean is going through init.");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Bean will destroy now.");
    }
}
```

**x.MainApp.java:**

```
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
        obj.getMessage();
    }
}
```

**y.MainApp.java:**

```
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld2");
        obj.getMessage();
        context.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

**beans.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <bean id="helloWorld" class="x.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World (1)" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="helloWorld2" class="y.HelloWorld"
        init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World (2)" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

**Results:**
Running `y.MainApp` (works as expected):

```
Bean is going through init. 
Your Message : Hello World (2)
Bean will destroy now.
```

Running `x.MainApp` (the init callback of `x.HelloWorld` is triggered by `y.HelloWorld`. Confused of this one.. any help is very much appreciated...)

```
Bean is going through init.
Your Message : Hello World (1)
```

Comment: If you put another init method in x.MainApp, it will be triggered too. You create a new application context with specified xml configuration, but it's not mean all of the beans are loaded at the moment you are creating the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify your init method like this:

```
public void init() {
    System.out.println("Bean with message '"+ message +"' is going through init.");
}
```

You will see that all beans are initialized at startup and that the message you see actually comes from the class with the init method.

If you don't want this behavior you can use lazy init:

```
<bean id="helloWorld2" class="y.HelloWorld"
      init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy" lazy-init="true">
```